# How I can copy .vimrc to docker guest OS?

Tags: docker

I want to copy `.vimrc` to virtual ubuntu environment on docker

So I using `docker cp` command, But it causes the error.

`docker cp ~/.vimrc 712365a951e7:~/.vimrc`

Error Messages:

```
-bash: /Users/username/.vimrc: Permission denied
no such directory
```

Why this command do not be successful?

Host Platform: OS X 10.11.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `~` get expanded as /Users/username/.vimrc
This means that your executed command looks like:

```
docker cp /Users/username/.vimrc 712365a951e7:/Users/username/.vimrc
```

...which fails because the /Users/username/ does not exists inside the container.

You would need to create the directory /Users/username/ first, or you would need to place your .vimrc in an existing directory. Try something like

```
docker cp /Users/username/.vimrc 712365a951e7:/etc/.vimrc
```